# What happens when you change property parameter in a method without ref (C#)

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, ref

I am working with some Legacy code. I general method that I usually would call like this:

```
Poco = MyMethod(Poco.Id) // Lookup PocoToReturn on Poco.Id and return PocoToReturn
```

are called in my Legacy like this:

```
MyLegacyMethod(Poco) // Lookup lookedUpPoco on Poco.Id, set Poco = lookedUpPoco and return (void)
```

The later work mostly but not always. I am struggling to understand when the later work and where it does not works (and should be fixed)

Consider the following execution of the code I are located at the end of this post:

1. `Facade.AppleFacade.GetApple()` is called
2. `Persist.ApplePersist.GetAppleInfo(appleInfo)` is called
3. `info = new  AppleInfo { Id = "newId", Name = "Test"}` is executed
4. `GetAppleInfo` in the persist returns to `GetApple` in the facade

**Expected:** Info.Id = "newId" and Info Name = "test"

**Actual:** Info.Id = "oldId" and Info Name = null

If I add `ref` to get `MyStrangeMethod(ref Poco)` the my Actual will be as Expected. I guess

I have 2-3 Questions:

- Why is `ref` neccessary in this case then other code wihtout ref is working without problems?
- In general, what is the difference between using `ref` and using no prefix for Objects of different type?
- (I think I know the answer to this) Why do I calls like `MyMethod(ref myPoco.myProperty)` result in compile time error *A property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter*

Below the code example I mention above

```
namespace Facade
{
    public class AppleFacade
    {
        public AppleInfo GetApple()
        {
            var appleInfo = new AppleInfo();
            appleInfo.Id = "oldId";
            _applePersist.LoadAppleInfo(appleInfo);
            return appleInfo;
        }
    }
}

namespace Persist
{
    public class ApplePersist
    {
        public void GetAppleInfo(AppleInfo info)
        {
            info = new AppleInfo
            {
                Id = "id",
                Name = "test"                
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless there's some behind the scenes trickery, your legacy code should never work.  I.E., `MyLegacyMethod(Poco) { set Poco = lookedUpPoco; return (void); }` should never be able to overwrite the caller's Poco object.  If you think that it is, then please try to provide a minimal example that demonstrates this.

Answer (score 0):

In C# class instances are [reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) and structs are [value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) (primitive types are value type too).
A variable of a reference type does not contain its data directly; it contains a reference to its data.
When you pass a reference type to a method you pass its **reference** value.

So, in `GetAppleInfo` you receive a new reference for the `appleInfo` object and you simple overwrite that with a new reference of the new AppleInfo instance.
This clearly does not change anything in the caller.
Your example is analogous to this:

```
AppleInfo appleInfo = new AppleInfo{ Name = "A"};
AppleInfo info = appleInfo; 
info = new AppleInfo{ Name = "B"};
// appleInfo.Name == "A"
```

If you pass a reference type by reference using `ref` (or `out`) then you are passing its **reference** by reference instead of value. This would be analogue to this:

```
AppleInfo a = new AppleInfo{ Name = "A"};
a = new AppleInfo{ Name = "B"};
// a.Name == "B"
```

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typos, I wrote it directly in the answer editor.